# jQuery UI: connect sortable lists through tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is [an example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs) at jQuery UI official site, showing how to connect sortable lists through tabs. But I want a modified version as follow: when the dragging element is moved over a tab, the tab become selected automatically, so that I can drop the element at any position inside the selected tab.

Have spent a hour trying different ways but didn't get good luck. Anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xq2x/1/. Only a few modifications the original one.

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable1, #sortable2"
    }).disableSelection();
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    var $tab_items = $("ul:first li", $tabs).droppable({
        accept: ".connectedSortable li",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        over: function(event, ui) {
            var $item = $(this);
            var $list = $($item.find("a").attr("href")).find(".connectedSortable");
            $tabs.tabs("select", $tab_items.index($item));
            ui.draggable.appendTo($list).show("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on this one, have a start but could use some insight from UI guys

http://jsfiddle.net/L8QAE/1/

Comment: I tried your code. The tab just disappears when a dragging element moves over it. I use firefox.

Comment: Yeah, its not working 100% as  stated, just posted incase someone else was hacking on it. Still playing with it..